# GeForce 650 Video Card for dual monitors with HDMI splitter

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I am trying to connect both of my TVs with my computer. I bought an HDMI splitter, and I am connecting the hdmi cable from my GeForce 650 to the input of the splitter, and connecting both hdmi output cables to my TVs. However, the computer is recognizing both TVs as one :(. I am extending the monitors and trying to change the resolution, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas will greatly help.

Thank you

Comment: An HDMI splitter will not make one output work as two. It is the same as plugging a headphone splitter in to your phone, you can now plug in two headsets and two people can listen to it. You can't have two people listening to two different things from a single output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah the splitter just copies the original signal, there is no way for the card to know you have two monitors.
But that card has one or two DVI sockets so you just have to buy a dvi to hdmi connector (super cheap) and you are good to go.